Unable to embed Resdiary on my Nuxt3 website without an iframe
I'm having trouble trying to embed the Resdiary prenotation widget in multiple locations.
I would like to embed it using this code:
<div id="rd-widget-frame" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;"></div>

<input id="rdwidgeturl" name="rdwidgeturl" value="https://booking.resdiary.com/widget/Standard/LOCATION/IDNUMBER?includeJquery=false" type="hidden">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://booking.resdiary.com/bundles/WidgetV2Loader.js"></script>

I inserted the script tag this way in the app.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
useHead({
  script: [
    {
      src: 'https://booking.resdiary.com/bundles/WidgetV2Loader.js',
      // valid options are: 'head' | 'bodyClose' | 'bodyOpen'
      tagPosition: 'bodyClose'
    }
  ]
})
</script>

And in the page where i wanted it to display, inside the template tag:
<div id="rd-widget-frame" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;"></div>

<input id="rdwidgeturl" name="rdwidgeturl" value="https://booking.resdiary.com/widget/Standard/LOCATION/IDNUMBER?includeJquery=false" type="hidden">


But I can't get it to work, this is the only thing I get:
enter image description here
I also tried it on a plain HTML page to check the widget, but got the same result.
I would like to see the widget fully loaded like this one: https://booking.resdiary.com/widget/Standard/FraDiavoloMilanoSempione/37876

This is likely an issue of the script looking through the current document once when it gets loaded, to find any elements it needs to "convert" into such a widget. But if the script gets embedded already, before those elements actually exist, it won't work then. Is there any actual documentation available for this widget loader script? Sometimes they offer specific methods you can call, to make it go look for such elements again.

i tried to append the script with a timeout of 10 seconds after the page is loaded but nothing would happen, not event the screenshot i posted in the original question, as for the documentation it just says to do how i did it, and most of it is for wordpress and other website builders unfortunately

If you check the content of the WidgetV2Loader.js script, it isn't actually all too complex - but it triggers its functionality via window.onload=function(){...}, and within your vue environment, that event won't fire any more at this point. If I am reading this right, it doesn't appear to do much more, than to make sure jQuery & jQuery UI are loaded - and then it creates an iframe and assigns it the source URL from the rdwidgeturl input field. [...]

[...] I am not sure if it does anything more than that (maybe automatically resize the iframe) - but for the basic functionality, you could just ditch the script completely, and embed the target URL via an iframe element yourself ...

i might just go with that route at this point, thanks for help!
